# Issue with Object Mode Hair vs. Particle Edit Hair (Interpolated Children)

Tags: particles

I am having an issue with the hair showing differently between modes. I already deleted a lot of the particles on the top of the head. I don't want to get rid of interpolated children, since this gives the hair the thickness and general shape I'm going for, and I don't want the hair to be pushed over the eye.

[image: Particle Edit Mode]

[image: Object Mode]

[image: Particle View]